# C# LINQ でファイルの更新日付でソートする時に新しい日付、古い時間順に並べたい

Tags: c#, linq

こんにちは。
C# のLINQ だと思うのですが、少しむずかしくて、質問させてください。

現在、次のようにして、
ディレクトリのサブフォルダを一覧しています。

```
    string folderPath = 任意のどこか
    string[] filePaths;

    filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(
        folderPath,
        "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories
    ).OrderBy(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f)).ToArray<string>();
```

ファイルの更新日時の古いものから順番ということでOrderByしています。

このソートを、少し複雑に、

更新"日付"に対して、新しいものから古いもの
更新"時間"に対して、古いものから新しいもの

にしたいと思っていますが、
この条件をどのように記載すればいいのかがわかりません。

ご存知でしたら、よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending(v=vs.110).aspx)で降順に並べます。
- [ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx)でOrderByで同位だった値に対して並べ替え条件を追加できます。
- [Dateプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)で日付を取り出せます。
- [TimeOfDayプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx)で時刻を取り出せます。

以上をまとめると

```
filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f).Date)
    .ThenBy(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f).TimeOfDay)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ばっちりうまくいきました！